# How can I change which view wins over two using the same path?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I have two views in Drupal 8.

1. The standard **Taxonomy term (content)** view, path: `/taxonomy/term/%`
2. My custom view for just one term at path: `/term-alias`

When I go to my custom term, I see the view for all terms (#1), when I want to force it to #2.  How can I do that?

Comment: Try the internal path /taxonomy/term/123, the alias gets replaced by the internal path before routing.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!  If you add that as an answer I'll be happy to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the internal path of the term:

```
/taxonomy/term/123
```

Route matching operates only on internal (unaliased) paths and route #2 having more fixed parts wins.

See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Routing%21RouteCompiler.php/function/RouteCompiler%3A%3AgetFit/9.0.x